# How can i get day from a date

Tags: javascript, html

I'm from The Netherlands and I'm in school. I have a date but now I want to show a weekday from that date.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function getWeekday(d) {
    alert (d);
    var date = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Zondag";
    weekday[1] = "Maandag";
    weekday[2] = "Dinsdag";
    weekday[3] = "Woensdag";
    weekday[4] = "Donderdag";
    weekday[5] = "Vrijdag";
    weekday[6] = "Zaterdag";
    }


    function d() {
    document.getElementById("Weekdag").innerHTML = getWeekday ("2050-01-01");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Laat een weekdag zien</p>

<button onclick="d()">Klik voor weekdag</button>

<p id="Weekdag"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Asking questions on Stack Overflow is not an alternative to research. First, do basic research, including [a thorough search here](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+get+day+of+week), and then when posting your question explain what research you've done.

Comment: Also check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Here is a working code: http://codepen.io/yosvelquintero/pen/yVpwRW

Answer (score 3):

using your `Date` instance, call [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay). Sunday is `0` and so on.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay (le me is just adding a reference)

Comment: @GottZ notice i linked the function name.

Comment: oh nice. did not notice. good work :D

Comment: yeah but im not so good in this, can you help me more?

Comment: @Dimitri that sounds like a specific, new question is coming - perhaps your should start a new post.